# Як правильно перекласти retail measurement?

Tags: переклад, from-english, документація

Зіткнулась із необхідністю перекласти на українську мову **retail measurement**.

[Cambridge dicionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retail-management) дає лише тлумачення поняття *retail management*

> noun [ U ] UK ​  US ​  COMMERCE, MANAGEMENT ​ the activity of managing
>   stores that sell goods to the public:
>
> She has worked in retail management and customer service.

а також поняття [work measurement](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/work-measurement) .

Але жодне з цих не підходить, хоча можна сформувати загальне уявлення, що *retail* - роздрібна торгівля, а *measurement* - вимірювання, зважаючи на [це](http://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/measurement) і [це](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/measurement) джерело, наприклад.

**То як правильно у документації перекласти саме словосполучення retail measurement?**

Comment: Можете контекст навести? Не виключено, що в тексті описка або помилка виправлення автокоректором.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вимірювання роздробу**.

> The retail measurement service (RMS) tracks the sales of goods from retailers to consumers, at specific outlets in a predefined geographical area.

Переклад:

> Служба вимірювання роздробу (СВР) відстежує продажі товарів роздрібними продавцями споживачам, у певних точках продажу в наперед визначеній зоні.